# I need to set up xml tags in some order

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have xml like this:

```
<tt>
   <cpost/>
   <cpost/>
   <gx2tov />
   <kodp/>
   <Sertif1/>
   <Sertif1/>
   <slmat/>
</tt>
```

But I need to change it to:

```
<tt>
   <slmat/>
   <cpost/>
   <cpost/>
   <kodp/>
   <gx2tov />
   <Sertif1/>
   <Sertif1/>
</tt>
```

How can I do that using T SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an accepted answer already but it will work with empty nodes only. In this case you could just type in the XML as you need it...

Some more approaches:

I added some id-attributes to distinguish the identical elements

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<tt>
   <cpost id="1"/>
   <cpost id="2"/>
   <gx2tov/>
   <kodp/>
   <Sertif1 id="1"/>
   <Sertif1 id="2"/>
   <slmat/>
</tt>';
```

### Place `<slmat>` at the top

You can use `.query()` to get a full node, which you can use `AS [node()]` in a `SELECT ... FOR XML PATH()`. This query will place `<slmat>` at the top, and will place all with a different name behind (original order):

```
SELECT @xml.query(N'/tt/slmat') AS [node()]
      ,@xml.query(N'/tt/*[local-name()!="slmat"]') AS [node()]      
FOR XML PATH(N'tt');
```

That's the same as above, but as one single `XQuery`

```
SELECT @xml.query
('
    <tt>
    {tt/slmat}
    {tt/*[local-name()!="slmat"]}
    </tt>
');
```

### Set a specific order for all nodes explicitly

If you want to set a specific order for your elements, you might place them explicitly (now I use `.nodes()`, but you could go without too - as above):

```
SELECT tt.query(N'slmat') AS [node()]
      ,tt.query(N'cpost') AS [node()] 
      ,tt.query(N'kodp') AS [node()] 
      ,tt.query(N'gx2tov') AS [node()] 
      ,tt.query(N'Sertif1') AS [node()] 
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/tt') AS A(tt)
FOR XML PATH(N'tt');
```

As `XQuery` (now with a variable, but you could use the root directly - as above)

```
SELECT @xml.query
('
    let $t:=/tt
    return
    <tt>
    {$t/slmat}
    {$t/cpost}
    {$t/kodp}
    {$t/gx2tov}
    {$t/Sertif1}
    </tt>
');
```

All have the same result...

Comment: Hello, Shnugo! Thank you for your answer! Yes, there was a problem tha it  works with empty nodes only but it pushed to right directioin to solve my problem. Do you have a links where I can find full information or documentation about t-sql xml functions? because Ms site isn't helplful at this question

Comment: @SashaFes At [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-type-methods) you find the functions of the `XML` data type, and [at this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-expressions) you'll find more about SQL Server's (limited) `XQuery` support

Answer (score 0):

You can delete and insert nodes:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = N'<tt>
   <cpost/>
   <cpost/>
   <gx2tov />
   <kodp/>
   <Sertif1/>
   <Sertif1/>
   <slmat/>
</tt>'

SET @xml.modify('delete tt/slmat[1]')
SET @xml.modify('insert <slmat /> as first into tt[1]')

SELECT @xml
```

Or, you can reorder all your nodes:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = N'<tt>
   <cpost/>
   <cpost/>
   <gx2tov />
   <kodp/>
   <Sertif1/>
   <Sertif1/>
   <slmat/>
</tt>'

SELECT
    CONVERT(xml, '<' +t.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') + ' />')
FROM @xml.nodes('*/*') AS t(t)
ORDER BY t.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)')
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('tt')
```

Comment: Thank you, Backs!

Comment: if I have another table with sort order how can I grab order from that table and use in this code?

Comment: found way to do that SELECT
    t.query('.')
FROM @xml.nodes('*/*') AS t(t)
ORDER BY  case t.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)')
when 'slmat' then 1
when 'cpost' then 2
 when  'kodp' then 3
  when 'gx2tov' then 4
  when 'Sertif1' then 5
end
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('tt')

Comment: @SashaFes you can join to any other table as well

Comment: This is - uhm - an answer to the given question actually... But if you'd have to deal with empty elements, you were faster to type the XML manually... Your first solution is procedural and very slow, especially, if you have to do this over and over. If `<slmat>` would contain anything, it's lost... The second is super complicated for no reason... and you are building XML on string level, something one should avoid if ever possible...