# SQL Server variable in XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have code like this:

```
declare @Temp TABLE (text varchar(max));

DECLARE @xml XML = N'<tt>
   <cpost s="a" cena="0.0000" cpost_id="16385" flprt="1" moq="0"
valuta_id="2" nmatr_id="14117" norg_id="1791" />
   <cpost s="a" norg_id="3883" nmatr_id="14117" valuta_id="2" moq="0"
flprt="0" cpost_id="9269" cena="0.0000" />
   <gx2tov s="a" gx_id="1" gx2tov_id="12435" nmatr_id="14117" />
   <kodp s="a" kodp_id="16496" nmatr_id="14117" norg_id="1847"
primtxt="дали на ДСК как 607194 (7863)" />
   <Sertif1 s="a" nmatr_id="14117" sertif_id="154" sertif1_id="13247" />
   <Sertif1 s="a" sertif1_id="13495" sertif_id="154" nmatr_id="14117" />
   <slmat s="a" akciz="0.00" artic="PP-46100" barcod3="4690401014360"
brand_id="7" c_prod="1.9200" c_zak="0.6290" dlina1="40.00"
dlina2="13.00" dlina21="0.00" dlina3="0.000" ed1_id="5" ed2_id="3"
ed3_id="12" Flbcdublno="0" fllock="0" flview="0" flweb="1"
fotost_id="46" karlst_id="9" kfp112="24" kfp12="24.00" kfp23="48.00"
kfs_id="1" kubfut="0.9041" kubfut2="0.0000" kubfut3="0.0000"
kubm="0.0256" kubm2="0.0000" kubm3="0.0000" man_id="234" maxkor="0"
minkor="0" nazv_id="8764" ngrup_id="16" nmatr_id="14117" osob_id="3"
pr_id="9" prcprib="0.0" razmer_id="23" shirina1="32.00" shirina2="5.00"
shirina21="0.00" shirina3="0.00" sitelink="/get-image/?xml_id=14117"
sortt_id="7402" tema_id="26" typecen_id="1" typeob_id="16"
typeper_id="3" val_id_pr="2" val_id_zak="2" vesupkg="4.70"
vesupkg2="0.18" vesupkg3="0.00" vesupkgn="4.22" vesupkgn2="0.00"
vesupkgn3="0.00" vidt_id="589" vysota1="20.00" vysota2="16.50"
vysota21="0.00" vysota3="0.00" />
   </tt>';

INSERT INTO @Temp
    SELECT '{$t/'+ attribute + '}' 
    FROM third
    ORDER BY number;

--select * from @Temp
SELECT @xml.query
('
    let $t:=/tt
    return
    <tt>
    +sql:variable(@Temp)    
    </tt>
');

--[sql:variable("@Count")]
```

It should be returning:

```
SELECT @xml.query
('
    let $t:=/tt
    return
    <tt>
    {$t/slmat}
    {$t/cpost}
    {$t/kodp}
    {$t/gx2tov}
    {$t/Sertif1}
    </tt>
');
```

but it's returning:

```
<tt>
    +sql:variable(@Temp)    
</tt>
```

Comment: I see, that you've adopted my solution from your last question and you are trying to develop this further... What you are trying, will not work... Are you trying to read the sort-order of your elements from a *template* table dynamically? You might create the full statement as string and use `EXEC` for execution (read about *dynamic SQL*). Maybe there's a chance with a `FLWOR` query (the "O" stands for *order by*). Please try to set up a full *mockup* scenario!

Comment: @Shnugo I didn't really delve into the question, rather the fact that sql:variable won't work for table variables. Do you think a solution with sql:column would be feasible?

Comment: @TT., nice to meet you again :-D I don't know exactly, what the OP needs... If I get this correctly (and the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44080781/5089204)), the OP wants to get the order of the elements dynamically from a side table (why ever). That means: create the `XQuery` dynamically. and execute this *somehow magically*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My magic crystall ball tells me, that you want to sort your elements according to an external list (a table). You might try it like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<tt>
  <cpost s="a" cena="0.0000" cpost_id="16385" flprt="1" moq="0" valuta_id="2" nmatr_id="14117" norg_id="1791" />
  <cpost s="a" norg_id="3883" nmatr_id="14117" valuta_id="2" moq="0" flprt="0" cpost_id="9269" cena="0.0000" />
  <gx2tov s="a" gx_id="1" gx2tov_id="12435" nmatr_id="14117" />
  <kodp s="a" kodp_id="16496" nmatr_id="14117" norg_id="1847" primtxt="дали на ДСК как 607194 (7863)" />
  <Sertif1 s="a" nmatr_id="14117" sertif_id="154" sertif1_id="13247" />
  <Sertif1 s="a" sertif1_id="13495" sertif_id="154" nmatr_id="14117" />
  <slmat s="a" akciz="0.00" artic="PP-46100" barcod3="4690401014360" brand_id="7" c_prod="1.9200" c_zak="0.6290" dlina1="40.00" dlina2="13.00" dlina21="0.00" dlina3="0.000" ed1_id="5" ed2_id="3" ed3_id="12" Flbcdublno="0" fllock="0" flview="0" flweb="1" fotost_id="46" karlst_id="9" kfp112="24" kfp12="24.00" kfp23="48.00" kfs_id="1" kubfut="0.9041" kubfut2="0.0000" kubfut3="0.0000" kubm="0.0256" kubm2="0.0000" kubm3="0.0000" man_id="234" maxkor="0" minkor="0" nazv_id="8764" ngrup_id="16" nmatr_id="14117" osob_id="3" pr_id="9" prcprib="0.0" razmer_id="23" shirina1="32.00" shirina2="5.00" shirina21="0.00" shirina3="0.00" sitelink="/get-image/?xml_id=14117" sortt_id="7402" tema_id="26" typecen_id="1" typeob_id="16" typeper_id="3" val_id_pr="2" val_id_zak="2" vesupkg="4.70" vesupkg2="0.18" vesupkg3="0.00" vesupkgn="4.22" vesupkgn2="0.00" vesupkgn3="0.00" vidt_id="589" vysota1="20.00" vysota2="16.50" vysota21="0.00" vysota3="0.00" />
</tt>';

DECLARE @SortOrder TABLE(element VARCHAR(100),inx INT);
INSERT INTO @SortOrder VALUES
 ('slmat',1)
,('cpost',2)
,('kodp',3)
,('gx2tov',4)
,('Sertif1',5);

SELECT --a.value(N'local-name(.)',N'nvarchar(max)') AS ElementName
        a.query(N'.') AS [node()]
        --so.inx
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/tt/*') A(a)
INNER JOIN @SortOrder AS so ON a.value(N'local-name(.)',N'nvarchar(max)')=so.element
ORDER BY so.inx
FOR XML PATH(N''),ROOT(N'tt')
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`sql:variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-extension-functions-sql-variable) function will only expose a value, not a table (a table is not a value).

> Exposes a variable that contains a SQL relational **value** inside an XQuery expression.

I think you'll be needing the [`sql:column`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-extension-functions-sql-column) function.